# integrity constraint violation: 1452 on POST

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am trying to create record via Post request from Angular. The foreign key i have setup from select. on post I am getting this error

json I am posting

```
{"customername":"fsdfsf","pan":"sdfsdff","customertype":"sdfsdfsdf","email":"sdfsdf@sdfk.com","mobile":"sdfsdfsdf","offadd":"dfsdfsdf","refererID":1}
```

error 500 internal server

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`auditCrm_db`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `customers_refererid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`refererID`) REFERENCES `referers` (`refererID`)) (SQL: insert into `customers` (`customername`, `pan`, `email`, `mobile`, `offadd`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (fsdfsf, sdfsdff, sdfsdf@sdfk.com, sdfsdfsdf, dfsdfsdf, 2014-11-09 21:50:37, 2014-11-09 21:50:37))"
```

My angular select element

```
 <select name="refererID" ng-model="customer.refererID" ng-options="referer.refererID*1 as referer.referername for referer in referers " class="" id="selReferer"></select>
```

also i have tried *1 instead of parseint but sameresult.

My schema customers

```
        $table->increments('customerID');
        $table->string('customername');
        $table->string('pan')->unique();
        $table->string('customertype');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->text('offadd');
        $table->text('comadd');
        $table->string('website');
        $table->string('now');
        $table->string('companyname');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->integer('refererID')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('refererID')
                ->references('refererID')->on('referers');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
```

Schema referers

```
        $table->increments('refererID');
        $table->string('referername');
        $table->string('companyname');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('offadd');
        $table->string('comadd');
        $table->string('dob');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
```

When posting my form I am getting this error. But If i insert from phpmyadmin row gets created. How to post with foreign key by setting value from select options. Angular select will be helpful

Comment: Leaving as a comment because I'm not sure, but looking at this: `(SQL: insert into `customers` (`customername`, `pan`, `email`, `mobile`, `offadd`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)` I don't see you trying to add a value for refererid, and you're expecting a foreign key there, so why isn't it there?

Comment: yes @McAdam331. I figured it out. I was passing the value. but my backend api was rejecting it. I needed to add protected fillable in my php. Thank you.

Comment: Oh okay. I am not familiar with angularjs, so I was just reading out of curiosity and that caught my attention haha. Glad you sorted it out.